# Why I get "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

There is code:

```
function search(list, q){
  var result = {};
  for(let id in list)(
    (!q.id    || (id == q.id)) &&
    (!q.name  || (list[id].name.search(q.name) > -1)) &&
    result[id] = list[id]
  );

  return result;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment    script.js:4
```

Why "&&" is wrong?

Comment: are you missing `if` before the first set of parentheses?

Comment: `result[id] = list[id]` should be `result[id] === list[id]` as it is a condition

Comment: @Aravind that is not correct.

Comment: @DanO "if" must not be important, because all logical operator in ( ), not { }

Comment: @TurarAbu see my answer: the problem is that your assignment expression at the end of the `&&` list is not in parentheses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the assignment operator, `=`, is a low-precedence operator, so it's being interpreted in a way you don't expect. If you put that last expression in parentheses, it works:

```
  for(let id in list)(
    (!q.id    || (id == q.id)) &&
    (!q.name  || (list[id].name.search(q.name) > -1)) &&
    (result[id] = list[id])
  );
```

Comment: The real problem is using logical operators for control flow.

Comment: @rockstar well sure :) But it's not erroneous and lots of hard-core library code does stuff like that, so people will see it in "respectable" places.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a typo in your code:

`result[id] = list[id]` should be `result[id] == list[id]` or `result[id] === list[id]`(if you're doing a strict comparison)

Comment: No. The code posted is using JavaScript logical short-circuiting operators to conditionally perform an operation. The change you suggest would make the code do nothing at all.

Comment: The trouble at 4'th line.

Comment: There's no way ```=``` is a short hand for ```==``` or ```===```. They have different meanings altogether. I checked in my console and it worked fine when I changed it to ```result[id] == list[id]```

Comment: @m-ketan he **wants** to use the assignment operator (`=`). If the statement does not perform an assignment, the code is useless.

Comment: @Pointy Oh I see it now.